# IntelliJ-İDEA code completion color

Tags: intellij-idea

After 192.6603.28 update(6 Sep 19), the color of the typed part in code completion(suggestion) changes to blue. I look for every color settings but cannot find code completion color settings. How can I change it?

Comment: You can check this solution : 【[java - Changing the font colour in IDEA code-completion window - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17283762/6264260)】 It works for me . Good luck for you !

Comment: @Lancer.Yan thank you